# Optimal AWS Product for serving a frequently changing file

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I currently have a traditional MEAN SPA website which is hosted on a server. I am considering moving to a (mostly) serverless architecture on AWS, using:

- S3 for hosting the public webite materials
- API Gateway for hosting the API
- Lambda to process most API functions
- DynamoDB as a data source

However, a critical component of my website still requires a server to run. This component collects binary data over TCP from multiple contributing sources, processes it, and creates a JSON file as output. This file updates every 2 seconds. This JSON file needs to be publicly available for the API to work.

I see my options as follows:

1. Expose the JSON file publicly from the server by running a lightweight http server
2. Through the aws cli from the server, use S3 to host the file in a accessible bucket

With either of the options above, it seems I can use the API gateway to expose the file. Is putting the file on S3 the correct "cloud" way to do this, or am I missing a better way? A concern of mine is getting charged a PUT operation fee every two seconds.

Comment: S3 seems like a bad solution here. Your lightweight http server solution is probably what I would go with. Do clients absolutely need the latest version of that file every 2 seconds? How often do clients go back to get an updated version of that file? Also, how large is the file?

Comment: @mark-b Yes, the SPA polls the API every 2 seconds to provide updated data to the website. The JSON is no larger than 20KB normally.

Comment: I think your cost for PUTs would be less than $6.50 per month, at one PUT every two seconds.

Comment: I think the eventual consistency aspect of S3's object updates would be a problem then. I'd probably run a small nginx server to serve that file. Maybe a few of them behind a load balancer, but then you'd need to use something like EFS to store the file.

Comment: @jarmod yep, but this is a niche website with a small user base. If I could avoid the S3 charges I could likely get the monthly costs below 4 dollars

Comment: @MarkB thanks, this is a low traffic website so that might be overkill. I will likely just serve it directly from EC2. Thanks!

Comment: Instead of serving this via a static file, have you thought about storing the JSON data in DynamoDB and exposing a Lambda function with API Gateway that would return that JSON data?

Comment: @MarkB I have not, likely because the program running on the server already made the data in a suitable format for me. That being said, this sounds like an alternatively valid solution and one I will investigate.

Comment: If the EC2 server has to exist anyway, it's probably cheapest to just continue serving the file via that same EC2 server.